# JS function match() is not working in iOS or Android. Always returns null

Tags: javascript, android, ios, match

So I have the loop below going through some names to check if what the user searched for (variable "s") matches one of the names or not. This all works great on every desktop or laptop but does not work on iOS or Android. I know that match() is compatible with these devices as stated in its documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Browser_compatibility).

You can see the code in action [here](http://uat.veinclinics.com/physicians-directory/).

Here is my loop:

```js
var s = search.val();
// if s is at least 3 characters
if ( 3 <= s.length ) {
 doctors.each(function() {
  var $this = $( this ),
  name = $this.find( '.vca-doctor-name' ).text().toLowerCase().trim();

  if ( null !== name.match( s ) ) {
   $this.parents( '.vca-physician-wrapper' ).fadeIn( 'fast' );
  }
  else {
   $this.parents( '.vca-physician-wrapper' ).fadeOut( 'fast' );
  }
 });

 reset.fadeIn( 'fast' );
 $( '.vca-physician-wrapper' ).addClass( 'float' );
}
else {
 doReset();
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Phones typically have keyboards that capitalize the first Letter. The page shows matches for "bak", but not "Bak".

```
if (name.match(s.toLowerCase())) {
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a situation like this before. I fixed it by using an explicit RegExp. So your code would turn into: `var s = new RegExp(search.val());`

Comment: I tested it and this will not solve the OP's problem. It merely turns `"Bak"` into `/Bak/` which still doesn't match "baker".